# Class Equation : $20 = 1 + 4 + 5 + 5 + 5$, normal subgroup of order $5$ not normal subgroup of order $4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have the following class equation: 
$$20 = 1 + 4 + 5 + 5 + 5$$

I know that there are subgroups of order $4$ and $5$ in $G$. I see this because $\vert G \vert = \vert \text{centralizer} \vert \cdot \vert \text{conjugacy class} \vert$ and the centralizer is a subgroup of $G$. So, we have $\vert \text{centralizer} \vert = 4$ and $\vert \text{centralizer} \vert = 5$, so there are subgroups of order $4$ and $5$ in $G$. However, I have been told that the subgroup of order $4$ is not normal and the subgroup of order $5$ is normal in $G$. I know that a normal subgroup is the union of conjugacy classes. Is there a way I can easily show their normality? Thank you.

Comment: There are just four elements of order $5$, so they must be the non-identity elements in a unique subgroup of order $5$, which must therefore be normal. On the other hand, there is more tha  one subgroup of order $4$, so they cannot be normal.

Comment: Thanks you @DerekHolt, how did you know that there were just 4 elements of order 5?

Comment: In your equation $20=1+4+5+5+5$ only the term $4$ can represent elements of order $5$.

Comment: So are there 15 elements of order 6? Is there a general way to find how many elements are of what order with regard to the class equation?

Comment: Why do you think there are $15$ elements of order $6$? It makes no sense at all, $6$ does not even divide the group order. The elements i the classes of size $5$ have centralizers of order $4$, so they could have order $2$ or $4$.

Comment: @ Derek Holt:I have one doubt.How to show that  G has subgroup of order 10.Here G is nonabelian.I don't konw how to check it.

Comment: @ASHWINISANKHE , nonabelian group of order 10 has subgroup of order 10  is possible only when, element of order 2 and 5 commutes but, I don't think this is always true!

Comment: Here, why only 4 elements of order 5. How to confirm there is no subgroup of order 5 other than the noted centralizer subgroup. Without using Sylow theory

Comment: Without using Sylow theory, can we use : normal subgroups are union of conjugacy classes here.

Answer (score 1):

The centralizers of the elements of the only conjugacy class of size $4$ have order:
$$|C_G(g)|=\frac{|G|}{\left|\operatorname{cl}(g)\right|}=\frac{20}{4}=5$$
In general $\langle g\rangle\le C_G(g)$, so in this case ($5$ prime and Lagrange) $\langle g\rangle= C_G(g)$. Therefore, there are precisely $4$ elements of order $5$, which then must be grouped into one single subgroup of order $5$, thence normal.

On the other hand, you'll not be able to build up a subgroup of order $4$ as the union of the unique central singleton (the set with the identity element) and some other noncentral conjugacy classes (in fact, all of them have size $4$ or $5$). So, a group of order $4$ (which exists because the centralizers of the elements of the conjugacy classes of size $5$ have order $4$) is not normal.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sylow-Theorem to show normality.$|G|=20=2^2*5$.Hence to get $n_5,1+5k/4,for k=0,1,2...$this means $n_5=1$.Hence G has normal subgroup of order 5.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's fairly trivial that any subgroup that is a union of conjugacy classes is normal (and conversely).

You can read off from the class equation that the union of the center,  which is evidently trivial,  and the conjugacy class of order $4$ can give a normal subgroup of order $5$.  (That doesn't mean it does;   but it might. )

Again,  the center is the conjugacy class of size $1$.  That's clearly the identity.   It needs to be in any subgroup.   So as you can see there's no way to put a $1$ together with a $4$ or a $5$ and get a $4$.  Thus no normal subgroup of order $4$.

So by looking at the class equation you can see what size normal subgroups are *possible*. That's you can rule some out.   But for instance in this case we need to check whether the subgroup of order $5$ is indeed normal.

The only possible normal subgroups are of order $5$ and $10$.  The other possibilities are ruled out by Lagrange and the class equation.

Answer (score 0):

If there are two subgroups of order $5$ say $H$ and $K$ then $o(HK)=o(H)o(K)=25>20$. Therefore there can only be one subgroup of order $5$ which implies it is a normal subgroup.

Let $G$ contain a normal subgroup $M$ of order $4$. Then $G$ is isomorphic to $M×H$. This implies $G$ is abelian. This contradicts the given class equation.
Therefore subgroup of order $4$ cannot be normal.